# Reading Data from Network Stream in TCP Listener

Tags: c#

I'm having a network stream which is having filename and filedata in it. I'm sending files in some chunks and each chunk carries the filename for easy identification. Can you please help me in reading the network stream properly and writing all of the data to the file stream.
I seem to miss few bytes when i write the data from network stream.
Say for example filename length will be in oth index and filename will start from 4th index.

```
    Client:

    int NoOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32
          (Math.Ceiling((Convert.ToDouble(Fs.Length))/ Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize)));
           int TotalLength = (NoOfPackets *4+fileNameByte.Length) +(int)Fs.Length,     CurrentPacketLength, counter = 0;
        netstream1 = client.GetStream();
          for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPackets+1 ; i++)
          {

              if (TotalLength > BufferSize)
              {
                  CurrentPacketLength = BufferSize;
                  TotalLength = TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength;
              }
              else
                  CurrentPacketLength = TotalLength;
              SendingBuffer = new byte[CurrentPacketLength];
             fileNameLength.CopyTo(SendingBuffer, 0);
              fileNameByte.CopyTo(SendingBuffer, 4);
              Fs.Read(SendingBuffer, 4 + fileNameByte.Length, CurrentPacketLength - (4 + fileNameByte.Length));
             netstream1.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, SendingBuffer.Length);
               netstream1.Flush();
                 }
```

Listener Code:

```
           client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                    //client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, true);
                    client.Client.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 300);
                    client.Client.SendTimeout = 300000;                     
                    client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 300000;
                    client.NoDelay = true;
                    NetworkStream netstream = client.GetStream();

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    bool first = true;
                    string fullPath = "";
                    byte[] RecData = new byte[512000];

                    while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read
                        (RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                    {

                        int fileNameLen = RecData[0];

                        if (fileNameLen > 0 && first)
                        {
                            string name1 = "", name2 = "";
                            first = false;

                            name1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RecData, 4, fileNameLen);


                            name2 = name1;

                            string folderName = "";
                            if (name2.Contains("\\"))
                            {
                                folderName = name2.Substring(0, name2.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                                if (!Directory.Exists("D:\\123\\" + folderName))
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\123\\" + folderName);

                            }
                            if (folderName != "")
                                fullPath = "D:\\123\\" + folderName + "\\" + name2.Substring(name2.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                            else
                                fullPath = "D:\\123\\" + name2.Substring(name2.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                        }


                        if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
                        {

                            //file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                                    {

                                        if (RecBytes - (4 + fileNameLen) > 0)
                                            file.Write(RecData, 4 + fileNameLen, RecBytes - (4 + fileNameLen));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (IOException)
                                {

                                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                                }
                            }
                            //using (file = File.Create(fullPath))
                            //{
                            //    file.Write(data, 4 + fileNameLen, (int)data.Length - (4 + fileNameLen));
                            //}


                        }
                        else
                        {

                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                                    {

                                        if (RecBytes - (4 + fileNameLen) > 0)
                                            file.Write(RecData, 4 + fileNameLen, RecBytes - (4 + fileNameLen));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (IOException)
                                {

                                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                                }
                            }

                        }


                    }

                    ms.Close();

                    netstream.Close();
                    client.Close();
```

Comment: Please show your relevant code and what you have tried.

Comment: With the given information it is impossible to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

even though you are as vague as anyone can be, still I would suggest that you create a structure so that serialization and de-serialization of data could be done in a known format!! and data loss could be avoided!! 
Again if your approach is known it would be great help in answering your question.